# Docker wont install numpy on ubunty 18.04 but same docker ile runs just fine on sagemaker notebook instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, numpy, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to build an image using the docker file below (using this [example](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own)). It works just fine on my notebook instance, but when I try to run it locally I get numpy errors like the below. I've spent hours trying to use other numpy versions, install python 3.8, use ubuntu 20.04 but it just leads to other error messages. It's making me think there is some underlying error, and the package error messages are just symptoms...why would the exact same docker files produce a different error message in a different environment? I thought they were downloading from the same source and running it containerized? I thought the whole point was that the container would build the same way no matter where you run it....and like I said, it gives no 3.8 version warning when I run the same image on the notebook instance (and I've verified that the same version of python gets installed in both cases). Why would numpy install behave differently?

```
Collecting numpy==1.16.2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/8d/6345b4f32b37945fedc1e027e83970005fc9c699068d2f566b82826515f2/numpy-1.16.2.zip (5.1MB)
Collecting scipy==1.2.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a9/b4/5598a706697d1e2929eaf7fe68898ef4bea76e4950b9efbe1ef396b8813a/scipy-1.2.1.tar.gz (23.1MB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-ua250hpf/numpy-1.24.2/setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    
    RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.8 required.
```

Docker file:

```
# Build an image that can do training and inference in SageMaker
# This is a Python 3 image that uses the nginx, gunicorn, flask stack
# for serving inferences in a stable way.

FROM ubuntu:18.04

MAINTAINER Amazon AI <sage-learner@amazon.com>


RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         wget \
         python3-pip \
         python3-setuptools \
         nginx \
         ca-certificates \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python3 --version
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip

# Here we get all python packages.
# There's substantial overlap between scipy and numpy that we eliminate by
# linking them together. Likewise, pip leaves the install caches populated which uses
# a significant amount of space. These optimizations save a fair amount of space in the
# image, which reduces start up time.
RUN pip --no-cache-dir install numpy==1.16.2 scipy==1.2.1 scikit-learn==0.20.2 pandas flask gunicorn

# Set some environment variables. PYTHONUNBUFFERED keeps Python from buffering our standard
# output stream, which means that logs can be delivered to the user quickly. PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE
# keeps Python from writing the .pyc files which are unnecessary in this case. We also update
# PATH so that the train and serve programs are found when the container is invoked.

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE
ENV PATH="/opt/program:${PATH}"

# Set up the program in the image
COPY decision_trees /opt/program
WORKDIR /opt/program
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 the `python3` package is Python 3.6 - [the package page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3) indicates this.  If you'd like Python 3.8, you need to install the `python3.8` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3.8).

Comment: why does it require this when run in one place and not the other though?

Comment: We don't know what version of Numpy you're using in the notebook.  You started with a 3 year old Docker - it's likely you'll need to do upgrades as Python libraries change very quickly.